# The contact form directs answer-banned users to an article on question bans

Tags: bug, help-center, post-ban

If an answer-banned user tries to use the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), they are supposed to select "My question or answer was denied". Doing so brings up text that speaks exclusively of question bans:

> Users who are banned from asking questions see the following error message when trying to post a new question:
>
> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. 
>   Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.
>
> The only way to end a posting ban is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or “time out“. Visit [our help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) for more details.

Both the link "our help page" and the button "Get more details" link to [question bans article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). There is no link to [answer bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans) page.

There *is* a link there at the very end of "question bans" page, but why would one read the entire text of "question bans" if that is not their problem?

Comment: There should be two options: one for a question being denied, and one for an answer being denied.

Comment: @apaderno: The simpler solution seems like it'd be to just link both the question ban and answer ban help center pages in the dialog box that appears (when you select "My question or answer was denied" from the dropdown below "What can we help you with?").

Comment: @V2Blast I agree the users should be given two different links (one for question bans and one for answer bans). That means the text quoted in the questions should be about answer bans and question bans, not just question bans. That's what I meant with "there should be two options."